# I get this error when executing The multi-part identifier "TMaterials.intMaterialID" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error when executing The multi-part identifier "TMaterials.intMaterialID" could not be bound.

```
Select TCustomers.intCustomerID, TJobs.intJobID, TMaterials.strDescription, TJobMaterials.intQuantity, TMaterials.monCost, (TMaterials.monCost * TJobMaterials.intQuantity) As TotalCost
From TMaterials, (
                Select Sum(TMaterials.monCost) AS TotalCost, Sum(TJobMaterials.intQuantity) As TotalQuanity
                From TJobMaterials
                INNER JOIN TMaterials ON TMaterials.intMaterialID = TJobMaterials.intMaterialID
                INNER JOIN TJobs ON TJobMaterials.intJobID = TJobs.intJobID
                WHere TJobs.intStatusID = 1
                ) sub

INNER JOIN TJobMaterials ON TMaterials.intMaterialID = TJobMaterials.intMaterialID
INNER JOIN TJobs ON TJobMaterials.intJobID = TJobs.intJobID
INNER JOIN TCustomers On TJobs.intCustomerID = TCustomers.intCustomerID
Where TJobs.intStatusID = 1
Order By TJobs.intJobID , TMaterials.intMaterialID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.

It is unclear what you want to accomplish.  But you can fix the syntax error by replacing the comma with `CROSS JOIN`.